# Why does MQTT acknowledge so slow?

Tags: mqtt

I wrote an MQTT client program, which runs at a computer (computer 1). The MQTT client program connects to an MQTT Broker with QoS=1 and publishes data to Broker periodically. I subscribe the Broker (Qos=1) from another computer (computer 2), using Mosquito utility. I found the data published to Broker will be delay delivered to publisher about 3 seconds. The delayed time is too long. I checked the codes and found the 3-second-delay time is from read_packet() which is to read back acknowledge from Broker. Why is there such long delay time? How can I figure it out? The Broker (MQTT server) is managed by my coworker. If the Broker is the cause, I can request them to help. But I need to know what could be the trouble source, so that I can check with them.

I can confirm the delay occurring at the time of reading back acknowledge from Broker by watching the debugging message from MQTT client program at computer 1. For Qos = 1, the client must read back acknowledge after sending (publishing) packets. I found 3-second delay time between sending packet and reading back acknowledge. Surely, I also found the delay at display of Mosquito_sub utility.

Comment: Please clarify your setup: You got 2 clients, first is periodically publishing a topic with `QoS=1` and the other subscribed to it (QoS?). Where exactly you notice the delay? `Publish from client1 to broker` or `delivery of message from broker to client2` or `PUBACK from broker to client1` ?

Comment: Perhaps start by testing against another broker; either a free internet based one (say [mosquitto](https://test.mosquitto.org/) or [hive](https://www.hivemq.com/public-mqtt-broker/)) or a locally installed one (Mosquitto is easy to get running). If there is no issue when publishing a comparable message to another broker this would suggest the issue issue is with your broker or the network between you and the broker.

Comment: I found the delay at two places: 1. display of Mosquito_sub at computer 2; 2. the debugging message delay between sending packets and waiting acknowledge from Broker.

Comment: In that case perhaps try testing message delivery times using mosquitto_pub & mosquitto_sub (ideally from a few different machines). This removes anything you have written from the equation meaning that if there are still delays the issue will be either the network or the broker (and you can easily demonstrate the issue to your coworker)..

Comment: @StanHuangatTaiwan The best way to find the issue is probably to have a look in to the broker logs. You might also test sending the publish without any subsrciber to that topic, so the broker should immediately acknowledge the publish and you can say if there is big delay between `client1 <-> broker`

Comment: I just did two tests as follows:
1. Instead of publishing data from my client program, I published data using Mosquitto utility and subscribed it using Mosquitto too. I found no delay response.
2. I removed codes calling read_packet() and codes following it for process returned packet, I found the delay packet display on Mosquitto's subscription disappeared.


So, from the above, I concluded that the delay of publish is due to reading back MQTT level acknowledge packet. I will explore why the Broker returns packet so slow.

Comment: @Odysseus The number of subscribers should have no effect on responding to a publish from a client, the broker should not be sending anything to the subscribers until it's finished the QOS handshake with the publisher. (There is no end to end delivery notification in MQTT).

Comment: @hardillb The MQTT spec says that the receiver can initiate forward message delivery before sending `PUBACK`. So if there is any subscriber, the broker **might** (not necessarily) forward the message first which results in a later `PUBACK`

Comment: @StanHuangatTaiwan this appears to indicate that the issue is with your application (assuming your test client/topic/message matches that used by your application). At QOS1 there is a single ACK so I don't think this is a broker issue (given no delay when using mosquitto_pub). The next step is probably to make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you can post here (quite possible you will find the problem whilst creating the example). Testing with a local broker would enable you to fully eliminate the broker as a cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming near instant network comms and nothing else strange going on the fact that you have recreated the problem with `mosquitto_sub` then this points to the MQTT broker being the source of the problem.

Without knowing what broker you are using and how heavily it is loaded it's hard to say more but you should look at the broker logs.

Comment: Since he had no delay when using `mosquitto_pub` and `mosquitto_sub` it seems to be clearly an issue of his client program and not at the broker side